# Alfa-Cypermethrin 97% Techwater solubility

Tags: aqueous-solution

Aloha, I am a farmer in Hawaii and have been having problems with fire ants. I recently purchased a kilogram of Alfa-Cypermethrin 97% Tech, a pesticide that I find is not soluble in water. I would really appreciate it if someone could advise me how to make it water soluble in a 5% solution. I have no knowledge of chemistry.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Why the vtc as homework?

Comment: How much could you dilute the water with say, ethyl alcohol or acetone?  In other words, must your solution contain any water, and if so how much?